# how to fetch specific element's internal element in python

Tags: python, html, dom

I have a web page snippet like this:

```
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr>
  <tr>
  ...
  <tr>
      <td>
      <td>
      <td>
      <td>
      ...
```

I need to fetch the td after justifying the tr's bgcolor.

```
trs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/ html / body / table / tbody / tr / td / div / div[3] / 
table / tbody / tr')

for tr in trs:
    if tr.get_attribute("bgcolor") == "#B3D9D9":
        
        try:
            tr.xpath('/td[6]/a').click() # problem is here
            time.sleep(3)
        except:
            break
```

Comment: Could you explain your question clearly ? Also post the HTML Code/ Link and what have you done so far.

Answer (score 0):

this is my testbed:

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr >
  <tr style="bgcolor: red">
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td><a href="/about">Jackson</a></td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

## Python

try:
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[@style='bgcolor: red']/td/a").click()
except NoSuchElementException:
...

Comment: if there are several trs has the attribute, driver.find_element_by_xpath only fetch the first one.